# Replacing toilet valve

Tags: toilet, valve

I noticed that my toilet was having issues, so I was going to work on it.
I turned the value off and discovered the valve doesn't work anymore (This seems to happen alot with 1980s turn valves). So I started looking to replace it, which I thought would be fairly straight forward.  But I seem to be having issues finding a replacement that I think will work.  I attached a photo of the pipe, because the issue seems to be that I have a 5/8" supply line.  I was looking for a push-to-connect (I know those are frowned upon) but I didn't see anything that size.  I can solder, even though it's not preferred.  Can someone suggest a replacement valve that would make sense?

[image]

Comment: Pipe sizes are internal diameter not outside size.  5/8 outside will be close to the standard 1/2 inch pipe size, depending on what the pipe is made from.  Quite sure google will find tables with pipe wall thickness, outside pipe sizes.

Comment: @crip659 Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I'd be looking at just replacing the guts, as that appears to be a standard supply valve (can't tell for sure since you've limited our view).  They make repair kits.

Comment: Compression fittings are much better than push-to-connect and require no soldering.

Answer (score 1):

1/2" **nominal** copper pipe/tubing is 5/8" **actual outside** diameter.

The hole **inside** is slightly bigger than 0.500" for all wall thicknesses.

One handy reference, no endorsement, plenty more to be found:

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/cts-copper-tubing-sizes-d_2112.html

Since there's no sign of threading there, it's probably a soldered valve on copper tubing/pipe.

Get a 1/4 turn shutoff valve to replace the failed valve. They do much better in that type of service than the multi-turn screw valves do.

Comment: Quite right. I would add that a replacement valve that uses a *compression fitting* for your very-common 1/2" (nominal) copper pipe is probably the **easiest** solution. As for me I prefer to solder a 1/2" C x MIP adapter to the pipe so I can use thread-on valves. Either option will require you to cut off that old valve, naturally.

Comment: If you'll be soldering on a new adapter, or a new 1/4 turn solder type valve, you can remove the old valve by heating it up and pulling it off (un-soldering it) and not lose any pipe length.